# Why an old value of an smart-contract property is retrieved instead of the most current one?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I've deployed a simple ERC721-compatible contract to the Polygon network:

```
contract MyContract is ERC721 {
    uint256 public counter;
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC721(name, symbol) {
        // ...
        counter = 0;
    }
    function myMethod(string memory _arg) public {
        // ...
        counter++;
    }
}
```

My only interaction with the contract is to simply fetch the value of `counter` and then call the `myMethod()`, all in a loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  const counter = (await contract.counter()).toNumber();
  console.log(`counter: ${counter}`);
  // ..
  const tx = await contract.connect(myAccount).myMethod(str);
  await tx.wait();
}
```

It's all fine; but *sometimes an old value of the "counter" is retrieved*, for example:

```
counter: 11                     counter: 96
counter: 12                     counter: 97
counter: 13                     counter: 98
counter: 14                     counter: 60  <---- ??!!
counter: 15                     counter: 100 ** corrected in the next iteration
counter: 12  <---- ??!!
counter: 17  ** corrected in the next iteration
```

Why is that? How should I avoid it?!

It worth noting: in the subsequent iterations, as per the example above, the `counter` is retrieved correctly and holds the most up-to-date value.

Comment: Can you share the contract address? ... Also, what node provider are you using? It's possible that they're caching some of the results and that these unexpected values are returned from the cache. Or maybe it's cached somewhere along the way between your app and the node.

Comment: @PetrHejda Thanks for the replay; I just can't share the address, but what I've posted is almost all the code in the contract! Regarding the "node provider", I'm just simply utilizing the HardHat's runtime environment, with no Modifications at all! The "caching" thing is rational, but how may I disable/bypass it?!

Comment: @PetrHejda Besides the rational "caching" thing; I was wondering, shall it cause due to the nature of blockchain in that a "node that is not updated yet, reports the old data back"?! In other words, the blockchain designates a node to reply back that doesn't have the most up-to-date information (is not synchronized) and thus reports old data? Is that even possible?!

Comment: Your node provider service might be connected to a cluster of nodes, and query one of them that is not updated. So yea, that's a possibility as well.